# 20.04 frozen while upgrading to 21.10

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, freeze

I am on 20.04 and my system was freezing almost daily ([see my question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405771/20-04-system-freezing-almost-daily-wont-even-respond-to-sysrq)).  After trying many things I decided to upgrade to 22.04.  However, I couldn't update to that version directly, so I started the upgrade to 21.10 by running `do-release-upgrade`.  It got to the part where it is removing packages, then it froze.

So my question is, how should I proceed?  Should I try `SysRq REISUB`?  Should I boot from a 20.04 disk and restore?  Do I ignore the `Enroll MOK` GRUB menu option?

Comment: Are you sure it froze?  Some steps can take *some time* (meaning an hour+ depending on resources/hardware being used & packages you have installed)  and it appears to be frozen but isn't.  You've also not said if you're asking about desktop system, server system etc. I'd be patient, and explore at a text terminal where it's up to & what the *release-upgrade* process is actually doing...

Comment: Release upgrades should not be expected to fix preexisting problems, but they can make those problems harder to diagnose and fix. Sometimes a release upgrade can actually compound preexisting issues. Also, 20.04 to 21.10 is not a supported upgrade path. Additionally, "trying many things" complicates the diagnostic process, since you generally need to explain all of the details of all of the things you tried in order to completely understand the current status of the device. With all of these factors combined, it seems most prudent that you should reinstall the OS.

Comment: I agree with guiverc and Nmath and I think the best option is a new install. Upgrading an unstable OS doesn't solve the freezing (or any other) problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled 20.04 and restored from backups, so the situation is resolved.  Thank you to those who commented.